# nrwl-nx/fastify - BDD/Feature only library

Tags: nrwl-nx

I am currently experimenting with an Nx workspace consisting of the typical division of private 'libraries' used to build a common set of fastify applications under 'lambdas'.
Yes, testing out the fastify/lambda-api plugin.
What I would like to do is to physically separate out into a separate folder on the root directory a 'features' library/application to run all my BDD/gherkin/cucumber-js tests against the applications and be able to have them run separately.
The reason for this is the endpoints due to variance can be used in combination on different lambdas/routers. (Yeah, there is a reason here...)

- features

  - endpoint-1a
  - endpoint-1b
  - endpoint-2a
  - endpoint-2b
- lambdas

  - lambda-1
  - lambda-2
- libraries

  - ...

I currently have setup everything but these 'e2e' type tests.
Am I better off creating this as a library and moving outside the private dir?
Currently do not see much indication in the documents that e2e is handled much differently.